# WordPress Gutenberg-Block with ESNext (withState, withSelect)

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

I'm new in developing Gutenberg-Blocks with ReactJS for WordPress.

At the moment I'm developing a block which contains all entries of my custom post type. The entries should be shown as a select-box in the block.

But I've got some problems with saving the selected value. After saving and reloading the page, the select-box shows the "select an option..." again.

My code in the index.js file:

```js
import {registerBlockType} from '@wordpress/blocks';
import {withSelect} from '@wordpress/data';
import {SelectControl} from "@wordpress/components";
import {withState} from '@wordpress/compose';

const MySelectControl = withState({
    chart: "0",
})
(
    ({chart, setState, ...props}) => (
        <SelectControl
            label="Bitte wählen Sie ein Diagramm aus: "
            value={chart}
            options={props.options}
            onChange={(chart) => {
                setState({chart});
            }}
        />
    )
);

registerBlockType('my_chart/charts', {
    title: 'Diagramm',
    icon: 'chart-bar',
    category: 'widgets',
    attributes: {
        chart: {
            type: 'number'
        }
    },
    edit: withSelect((select) => {
        const query = {per_page: -1};
        return {
            posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'my_charts', query),
        };
    })
    (
        ({posts, attributes, setAttributes}) => {
            if (!posts) {
                return 'Loading charts...';
            }
            if (posts && posts.length === 0) {
                return 'No charts found';
            }
            let options = [];

            // if posts found
            if (posts) {
                options.push({
                    value: 0,
                    label: 'Select an option...'
                });
                posts.forEach((post) => {
                    options.push(
                        {
                            value: post.id,
                            label: post.title.rendered
                        });
                });
            } else {
                options.push({
                    value: 0,
                    label: 'Loading charts...'
                });
            }
            return (<MySelectControl options={options}/>);
        }
    ),
    save: function (props) {
        return null;
    },
});
```

Does someone know what's going wrong here? I'm not sure if I use the right way to display a select-box of entries of a custom post type. I think the problem is:

```js
const MySelectControl = withState({
    chart: "0",
})
```

I set the value every time to "0". But how can I pass the already selected value to it?

If you need some more information please let me know.

Thanks,
Thorsten

Answer (score 2):

Okay guys, I've got a solution:

````
import {withSelect} from '@wordpress/data';
import {SelectControl} from "@wordpress/components";
import ReactSpinner from 'react-bootstrap-spinner'
import ServerSideRender from '@wordpress/server-side-render';

const MySelectControl =
    (
        ({chart, setAttributes, ...props}) => (
            <SelectControl
                label="Bitte wählen Sie ein Diagramm aus: "
                value={chart ? parseInt(chart) : 0}
                options={props.options}
                onChange={(chart) => {
                    setAttributes({
                        chart: chart
                    });
                }}
            />
        )
    );

registerBlockType('my_chart/charts', {
    title: 'Diagramm',
    icon: 'chart-bar',
    category: 'widgets',
    attributes: {
        chart: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    edit: withSelect((select) => {
        const query = {per_page: -1};
        return {
            posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'my_charts', query),
        };
    })
    (
        ({posts, setAttributes, className, attributes}) => {
            if (!posts) {
                return <p className={className}>
                    <ReactSpinner type="border" size="2">
                        <span className="sr-only">Diagramme werden geladen...</span>
                    </ReactSpinner>
                </p>;
            }
            if (posts && posts.length === 0) {
                return '<p>Keine Diagramme gefunden</p>';
            }
            let options = [];

            // if posts found
            if (posts) {
                options.push({
                    value: 0,
                    label: 'Bitte auswählen...'
                });
                posts.forEach((post) => {
                    options.push(
                        {
                            value: post.id,
                            label: post.title.rendered
                        });
                });
            }

            return (
                <div className={className}>
                    <MySelectControl key={attributes.chart}
                                     setAttributes={setAttributes}
                                     options={options}
                                     chart={attributes.chart}/>

                    <ServerSideRender
                        block="my-charts-importer/charts"
                        attributes={ attributes }
                    />
                </div>
            );
        }
    ),
    save: function () {
        return null;
    },
});```
````